# Zapier: Wait for a minimum of 2 Webhook notifications before sending email

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I have an Axis P5512 video camera in my Garage that i want to alert me if i leave the garage door open for longer than 20 minutes. I have a rule set up on the camera to hit a Zapier Webhook URL if the camera detects motion.

[image: Axis P5512 Rule]

I then wait 10 minutes before the camera should hit Zapier with another notification

[image: Zapier Zap]

Im struggling to configure the 2nd Action in Zapier to wait for a minimum of 2 Webhook notifications from the Camera before alerting me via email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work. I need to introduce a few more steps in Zapier.

[image: Garage Door Notifier]

Zapier has a native Storage App so i stored the number of notifications coming from the Axis P5512 on that and then when it got triggered twice it pings me an email. One useful aspect of the camera itself is the ability to add a delay between the notifications in the cameras settings. So i wait 10 minutes between notifications before it is allowed to get triggered again.

[image: Delay between Notifications]